# template output not updated when updating model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to Ember.js and I'm trying to update a status variable in a model, but the view doesn't update when I do change it.

This is the javascript code for what I'm trying to do:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.EventBus = Ember.Object.extend({
    eventBus: null,
    connect: function() {
        Ember.run.later(this, function() {
            App.Sessiondata.connection.status = "Online";
            console.log("status: " + App.Sessiondata.connection.status)
        }, 2000)
    }.on('init')
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('home', { path: '/' });
});

App.Sessiondata = {
    connection : {
        status: 'Offline',
        statusClass: 'alert-error',
        retryInterval: 20000,
        maxAttempts: 5
    },
    user : {
        fullname: 'Dummy User',
        email: 'dummy@email.com'
    },
};

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Sessiondata;
    }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    eventbus: App.EventBus.create()
})
```

And here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k82Lhj0j/

The idea is to update the connection status once the eventbus is open.
For this small test I'm ignoring the real eventbus code (it does work, but not really relevant for this test) and simply using a run.later to simulate similar behaviour.

As you can see, the result is always "Status: Offline" while it should become "Status: Online" after 2 seconds.

I'm probably doing something wrong in the spirit of how Ember.js works, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying a normal javascript object, not an Ember object. If you are not using ember's 'set' method there is no way Ember will notice a property was changed and templates need updates.
This works (simplified your example):

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yaliyo/1/edit

That being said, you will now have  to deal with the other issue to find a place to store your Sessiondata etc. ApplicationController is an option, but probably not the best.

Comment: Allright, thanks. I knew it was something obvious, but I'm not used to having specific objects instead of just plain, normal javascript objects.

Comment: And yes, you are right about finding a place to store the Sessiondata.
That's actually related to another issue I'm currently experiencing with Ember.js: where do you put data/code that should be available application wide ?
E.g. the Eventbus code will have to be expanded with extra methods, such as send, publish, etc and those should be accessible from within the whole application

(Edit: fixed typo)